# Queue fulling when start uwsgi docker container

Tags: python, uwsgi

When i start my uwsgi container i get this error.

`uWSGI listen queue of socket ":8000" (fd: 6) full !!! (75575376/64)`

I tried a solution with increasing number of listen sockets but they are too much and this problem did not solve.

2.0.18 uwsgi version

2.7.17 python version

linux ubuntu

Full log

```
uWSGI] getting YAML configuration from etc/uwsgi-dev.yaml
[uwsgi-static] added mapping for /local_avatars/ => local_avatars/
[uwsgi-static] added mapping for /static => /code/../zvq-web/htdocs/
[uwsgi-static] added mapping for /docs => docs/_build/html/
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Jul 18 14:55:22 2022] ***
compiled with version: 8.3.0 on 18 July 2022 14:36:53
os: Linux-5.10.104-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 17 17:05:54 UTC 2022
nodename: 8da3c1e437c5
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /code
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
*** dumping internal routing table ***
[rule: 0] subject: path_info regexp: ^/napi action: http:127.0.0.1:8001
[rule: 1] subject: path_info regexp: ^/tm action: http:127.0.0.1:8001
[rule: 2] subject: path_info regexp: ^/nstatic action: http:127.0.0.1:8001
[rule: 3] subject: path_info regexp: ^/sapi action: http:127.0.0.1:9005
*** end of the internal routing table ***
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...565 entry found
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
!!! it looks like your kernel does not support pthread robust mutexes !!!
!!! falling back to standard pthread mutexes !!!
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :8000 fd 6
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 2.7.17 (default, Apr 16 2020, 20:24:41)  [GCC 8.3.0]
Set PythonHome to /code/venv/
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x4000181500
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 304776 bytes (297 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
[uwsgi-signal] signum 0 registered (wid: 0 modifier1: 0 target: workers)
[uwsgi-signal] signum 1 registered (wid: 0 modifier1: 0 target: workers)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 18 seconds on interpreter 0x4000181500 pid: 88 (default app
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 88)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 103, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 105, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI mule 1 (pid: 108)
spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 2
```

Comment: Are you load testing? Why would there be 75575376 pending connections? Are you saying that happens on startup? Can you show the rest of the startup logs?

Comment: Okay, i will update my question

Comment: Outside of the complaints that you are running the app as root when you should not be, these startup logs look fine. When does the error happen?

Comment: I just noticed this says python 2.7. Python 2.x has been EOL since jan 1st 2020.

Comment: This problem causes only on my mac m1, on other it works fine

Comment: I have a similar issue, captured in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73337421/starting-amd64-uwsgi-container-on-m1-mac-leads-to-extreme-queue-filling -- not using 2.7 this time.