# Starting amd64 uWSGI container on M1 Mac leads to extreme queue filling

Tags: python, linux, docker, uwsgi

When I attempt to start a container that holds a uWSGI service on my M1 Mac, I get what seems like an unlikely listen queue behaviour.  Logs below, followed by more details:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from ./config/uwsgi/uwsgi_cells.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.20 (64bit) on [Fri Aug 12 15:57:43 2022] ***
compiled with version: 10.2.1 20210110 on 12 August 2022 15:53:41
os: Linux-5.10.104-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 17 17:05:54 UTC 2022
nodename: 272fb4e4e089
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit enabled
detected number of CPU cores: 5
current working directory: /usr/local/employer
detected binary path: /usr/local/employer/venv/bin/uwsgi
*** dumping internal routing table ***
[rule: 0] subject: path_info regexp: ^/operations/healthcheck/liveness/ action: return:200
[rule: 1] subject: path_info regexp: ^/operations/healthcheck/readiness/ action: return:200
*** end of the internal routing table ***
*** dumping internal response routing table ***
[rule: 0] action: last:
*** end of the internal response routing table ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
- async cores set to 100 - fd table size: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
!!! it looks like your kernel does not support pthread robust mutexes !!!
!!! falling back to standard pthread mutexes !!!
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
[busyness] settings: min=10%, max=50%, overload=32, multiplier=8, respawn penalty=2
[busyness] backlog alert is set to 64 request(s), step is 1
[busyness] backlog non-zero alert is set to 5 second(s)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address :5000 fd 8
Python version: 3.9.13 (main, May 18 2022, 02:18:18)  [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x400015db30
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 400 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 123283388 bytes (120393 KB) for 1600 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking+async ***
Loading local Docker configuration...
Loading local Docker configuration...
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 15 seconds on interpreter 0x400015db30 pid: 1 (default app)
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 14, cores: 100)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 16, cores: 100)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 18, cores: 100)
running \"unix_signal:15 gracefully_kill_them_all\" (master-start)...
*** running gevent loop engine [addr:0x40000b2590] ***
Fri Aug 12 15:57:59 2022 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket \":5000\" (fd: 8) full !!! (26486256/64) ***
[busyness] 26486256 requests in listen queue, spawning 1 emergency worker(s) (1)!
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 29, cores: 100)
Fri Aug 12 15:58:00 2022 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket \":5000\" (fd: 8) full !!! (26486256/64) ***
[busyness] 26486256 requests in listen queue, spawning 1 emergency worker(s) (2)!
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 34, cores: 100)
Fri Aug 12 15:58:01 2022 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket \":5000\" (fd: 8) full !!! (26486256/64) ***
[busyness] 26486256 requests in listen queue, spawning 1 emergency worker(s) (3)!
spawned uWSGI worker 6 (pid: 39, cores: 100)
Fri Aug 12 15:58:02 2022 - *** uWSGI listen queue of socket \":5000\" (fd: 8) full !!! (26486256/64) ***
[busyness] 26486256 requests in listen queue, spawning 1 emergency worker(s) (4)!
spawned uWSGI worker 7 (pid: 44, cores: 100)
```

The key line is this:

```
*** uWSGI listen queue of socket \":5000\" (fd: 8) full !!! (26486256/64) ***
```

Which is repeated every second after service start-up.  Fairly obviously, I *don't* have 26486256 pending connections to my service.  Business continues trying to spawn new workers until it hits the maximum, but curiously making requests to the service does actually work.

I'm trying to discover what's causing the log spam, and if it's actually going to be an issue anywhere other than my development environment.  It's making it rather more difficult to see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I could not make requests to the service. Setting `master = false` in the `.ini` config file solved this issue for me. (Based on this post: https://bytemeta.vip/repo/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2406)

Comment: Unfortunately my app needs `master=true` in order to start up properly.